# Find the CDF of $Z_t=\alpha\sum_{j=1}^{t}[X_j\prod_{l=j+1}^{t}Y_l]$, a combination of linearly transformed i.i.d Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function, bernoulli-distribution

Given i.i.d Bernoulli random variables $X_i,(i=0,1,...,t)$ and where
$Y_i=1-\beta +(\beta-\alpha)X_i$, with $0<\alpha<1$, $0<\beta<1$.

**Is it possible to find a closed form cumulative distribution function for $Z_i$? Defined as:
$$\boxed{Z_t=\alpha\sum_{j=1}^{t}[X_j\prod_{l=j+1}^{t}Y_l]}$$**

It's clear that the state space of $Z_t$ ,in general, grows as $2^t$, and so I'm already skeptical that $\mathbb{P}(Z_t\leq z)$ can be written in a nice closed form. Another issue, for a given $t$, is that an ordering is not immediately obvious, at least to me. For example, suppose $t=3$, and we compare the resulting value of $Z_3$ with respect to the two sequences $A=(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0)$ & $B=(X_1=0,X_2=0,X_3=1)$. So,
$$Z_3^A=\alpha[(1-\beta)(1-\alpha)+(1-\beta)]$$ $$Z_3^B=\alpha$$
Then $Z_3^A=Z_3^B$ if,
$$\alpha[(1-\beta)(1-\alpha)+(1-\beta)]=\alpha \implies \alpha=\frac{1-2\beta}{1-\beta}$$
which is valid for $0<\beta<1/2$. $Z_3^A>Z_3^B$ and $Z_3^A<Z_3^B$ follow accordingly. The question then: Is there a clear way would one establish an ordering of the values of $Z_t$ with respect to the corresponding sequences $\{(X_1,X_2,...,X_t)\}$?

Comment: Is there some practical purpose behind this formula that might help to get an intuition behind this formula?

Comment: Is the index in the summation, $$l = j+1$$ , correct? The value of $j$ can become equal to $t$ and then $l$ is equal to $t+1$ but $X_{t+1}$ does not exist.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, I should have specified the convention that $\prod_{l>t}^t a_l=1$. So for example, if $t=3$, $Z_3=X_1Y_2Y_3+X_2Y_3+X_3$

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, as far as a practical purpose, yes there is one. But, it would require a rather lengthy explanation, and probably would not provide much help with intuition. However $Z_t$, can be written as a recursive relation, similar to an autoregressive process except with a bit of a random twist. $Z_t=Y_tZ_{t-1}+\alpha X_t$. Perhaps this helps.

Comment: That autoregressive process helps a lot! I was trying to analyse the sum in the reverse direction of the autoregressive process but possibly that is not so smart. The formula that you show makes much more sense. It looks like a sum of exponentially decaying shocks.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, A sum of exponentially decaying shocks is a good description, that is essentially what it is, although because this is discrete it's more apt to say geometrically decaying shocks.

Comment: What values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ do you have? If they are small, then you can approximate the decay reasonably well with non-discrete process.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, The values can change depending on the experiment, but in general, $\alpha,\beta\in (0,1)$.

Comment: and the Bernoulli variable, what is p(X=1)?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, Because I defined $X_i\ (i=1,\cdots\ t)$ as i.i.d, $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=p\ ,\forall\ i$. So, there is no particular restriction on what value $p$ can take, but for all $X_i$, $p$ is the same.

Comment: I was hoping that you could restrict this problem further. The problem becomes entirely different depending on whether the $p$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are close to 1 or close 0. (That is another reason why I asked about a background such that an idea of the range of application is more clear)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Indeed, it is a rich family of distributions. For $\alpha=0.5$, $\beta\approx 0$, and $p=0.5$, it almost looks $U(0,1)$.

Comment: Interesting case. The resemblance with a uniform distribution is because it is almost like converting a random binary number/fraction, but instead of adding $0.5^k$ for a $1$ on the $k-th$ position you are slightly changing it.

Comment: So in which section of the family are you?

Comment: In practice & theory, the parameters could be anywhere in the given ranges. I'm writing a general theory paper, so I have no specific section of the family in which I'm specifically working. Broadly speaking, this is a portion of a model dealing with social systems.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, I think this paper shows pretty definitively that a nice efficiently computable CDF is out of the question. What do you think? Here they even have a clear order! https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Deepesh-Bhati/publication/265511396_Distributions_of_sums_of_geometrically_weighted_finite_valued_discrete_random_variables/links/54112a320cf2df04e75d71f7/Distributions-of-sums-of-geometrically-weighted-finite-valued-discrete-random-variables.pdf

Comment: I will look at that article. I was personally thinking about solving the case when the steps are small, such that it might approximately be turned into a Fokker Planck differential equation.

Comment: Currently I am on page 3 of that article, and I am thinking... why? I personally find it very hard to do mathematics, and especially mathematical statistics, without knowing which direction or purpose it is going to.

Comment: While I am still figuring out this stuff, I believe that @PeterO. might be interested as well. I am just a novice mathematician that works well with practical problems, and this seems a bit more theoretic.